# XML Obtain multiple values

Tags: php, xml

I have the below XML file. There are 4 rows constantly repeated for different websites.
These are _URL _Away _Home _Draw. Each of these is prepended by the website. I need to compare all of the _Away rows to find the highest value, but there may sometimes be 1 of these rows and other times there can be as many as 32. What I would like to know is, is there a way to get these by defining the end of the string without having to explicitly declare the entire  string for each website?

```
<XMLSOCCER.COM>
    <Odds>
        <Id>1547</Id>
        <_10Bet_Home_Home>1.31</_10Bet_Home_Home>
        <_10Bet_Home_Url>http://en.10bet.com</_10Bet_Home_Url>
        <_10Bet_Home_Away>8.50</_10Bet_Home_Away>
        <_10Bet_Home_Draw>5.40</_10Bet_Home_Draw>
        <Bet_At_Home_Home>1.25</Bet_At_Home_Home>
        <Bet_At_Home_Url>http://www.bet-at-home.com/</Bet_At_Home_Url>
        <Bet_At_Home_Away>10.00</Bet_At_Home_Away>
        <Bet_At_Home_Draw>5.75</Bet_At_Home_Draw>
        <Bet365_Url>http://www.bet365.com/</Bet365_Url>
        <Bet365_Home>1.30</Bet365_Home>
        <Bet365_Away>9.00</Bet365_Away>
        <Bet365_Draw>5.50</Bet365_Draw>
        <BetVictor_Home>1.30</BetVictor_Home>
        <BetVictor_Url>http://www.betvictor.com/</BetVictor_Url>
        <BetVictor_Away>9.00</BetVictor_Away>
        <BetVictor_Draw>5.40</BetVictor_Draw>
        <Bwin_Home>1.28</Bwin_Home>
    </Odds>
</XMLSOCCER.COM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath to fetch all nodes ending with `_Away`. [Here's a code snippet](http://codepad.org/WcvOeuKG) that accomplishes what you want:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<XMLSOCCER.COM>
<Odds>
    <Id>1547</Id>
    <_10Bet_Home_Home>1.31</_10Bet_Home_Home>
    <_10Bet_Home_Url>http://en.10bet.com</_10Bet_Home_Url>
    <_10Bet_Home_Away>8.50</_10Bet_Home_Away>
    <_10Bet_Home_Draw>5.40</_10Bet_Home_Draw>
    <Bet_At_Home_Home>1.25</Bet_At_Home_Home>
    <Bet_At_Home_Url>http://www.bet-at-home.com/</Bet_At_Home_Url>
    <Bet_At_Home_Away>10.00</Bet_At_Home_Away>
    <Bet_At_Home_Draw>5.75</Bet_At_Home_Draw>
    <Bet365_Url>http://www.bet365.com/</Bet365_Url>
    <Bet365_Home>1.30</Bet365_Home>
    <Bet365_Away>9.00</Bet365_Away>
    <Bet365_Draw>5.50</Bet365_Draw>
    <BetVictor_Home>1.30</BetVictor_Home>
    <BetVictor_Url>http://www.betvictor.com/</BetVictor_Url>
    <BetVictor_Away>9.00</BetVictor_Away>
    <BetVictor_Draw>5.40</BetVictor_Draw>
    <Bwin_Home>1.28</Bwin_Home>
</Odds>
</XMLSOCCER.COM>
XML;

$sxe                 = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$nodesEndingWithAway = $sxe->xpath('//*[substring(name(),string-length(name())-3) = "Away"]');

$highestValue = 0;
$nodeName     = '';

foreach ($nodesEndingWithAway as $node) {
    if ((float) $node > $highestValue) {
        $highestValue = (float) $node;
        $nodeName     = $node->getName();
    }
}

echo "Highest value is {$highestValue} from node {$nodeName}.\n";
```

#### Output:

```
Highest value is 10 from node Bet_At_Home_Away.
```

**Note**: I think it would be possible to accomplish it with a single XPath expression without the need to process the nodes with the `foreach`.

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks. Is there a way to also store the url and prefix of the name of which value was saved. I.e if Bet365s value was the highest I need to also get their URL and the prefix Bet365

Comment: That xpath is neat, but keep in mind that it could mismatch on elements that had "_Away" elsewhere in the name. It's not strictly matching the end of the name.

Comment: @Max This is a very different question, isn't it.

Comment: I was just wondering if it was a simple process to obtain the prefix.

Comment: I have been able to retrieve the node name easily that is satisfied. The major problem now is like @James Holderness said

Comment: @Max Look at the xpath expression in my answer if you are are concerned about getting an exact match. And I think michi's answer would work too, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: Given the comments I've updated the XPath query to match nodes ending with `_Away` instead of using the `contain()` function. Additionally I show you how to get the node name you requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with XPath.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($filename);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('/XMLSOCCER.COM/Odds/*[substring(name(),string-length(name())-3) = "Away"]');

$maxValue = 0;
foreach ($elements as $element) {
  $value = floatval($element->nodeValue);
  $maxValue = max($maxValue, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: very compressed:

```
$maxbid = max(array_map('floatval', $xml->xpath("//*[substring(name(),string-length(name())-" . (strlen($search) - 1) . ") = '$search']")));
```

in several steps:

use `simplexml` and `xpath`:

```
$search = "_Away";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);
$results = $xml->xpath("//*[substring(name(),string-length(name())-" . (strlen($search) - 1) . ") = '$search']");
```

Loop through your results:

```
foreach ($results as $result) echo "$result <br />";
```

Print highest result:

```
echo "highest: " . number_format(max(array_map('floatval', $results)), 2, '.', ',');
```

See it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/iEpGz9